# How to fix KafkaTimeoutError when connecting to Red Panda using kafka-python

Tags: python, kafka-producer-api, redpanda

I get the following error when trying to connect a `kafka-python` producer to my Red Panda database.

```
KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
```

I have a development environment running on WSL with the Red Pandas container on docker desktop. Red Panda is allocated 1GB of RAM so I don't believe it is a memory issue.

I used the following to connect to my Red Panda broker:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers = '192.168.2.28:19092', 
    security_protocol = 'SSL',
    api_version=(0, 10, 1)
)
```

I had to add both the `security_protocol` and the `api_version` in order for the producer to connect. I can assume it's connected as I am not getting any connection errors when that code is run.

I then try to send test data using the following and I receive the error:

```
producer.send('test', b'Hello, World!')
```

I have also tried not assigning the text as bytes and I get the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this error or have experience connecting producers to Red Panda, I am also open to using `confluent-kafka`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need SSL if you didn’t enable SSL in Redpanda.
If you enabled SSL, you will also need to configure the cert or keystore in your producer.
I don’t think the API version is relevant though. Hope that helps.